# Show that if $f$ is growing and bounded on $(a,b)$ than $\lim\limits_{x\searrow a}f$ and $\lim\limits_{x\nearrow b}f$ exist

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

Show that if $f$ is growing and bounded on $(a,b)$ than $\lim\limits_{x\searrow a}f$ and $\lim\limits_{x\nearrow b}f$ exist.

---

Since $f$ is bounded, there exists $\inf f$ and $\sup f$.

And since $f$ is growing, **(1)** $\forall x,y \in (a,b):x<y \Longrightarrow f(x) \le f(y)$

The definition of **(2)** $\sup f$ says $\forall x \in (a,b): f(x) \le \sup f$

Now we show:

$\forall \epsilon >0 \,\,\, \exists \delta>0 \,\,\,x \in (a,b):0<|x-b|< \delta \Longrightarrow |f(x)-\eta|<\epsilon$

We set $x:=b-\frac{\delta}{2}$ for any $\delta> 0$ and $0<|b-\frac{\delta}{2}-b|=|\frac{\delta}{2}]<\delta$ always holds.

Obviously $b-\frac{\delta}{2}\in (a,b)$ which means because of **(2)** $f(b-\frac{\delta}{2})\le \sup f$

If we additionally take $\sup f-\epsilon $ from the definition of the supremum it follows that:

$\sup f-\epsilon \in f((a,b)), \forall \epsilon >0$

Choosing $\delta$ in regards to any $\epsilon$ and since **(1)** gives us the inequation:

$\sup f-\epsilon < f(b-\frac{\delta}{2})\le \sup f$

Let $\sup f:= \eta$, we get $\eta-\epsilon < f(b-\frac{\delta}{2})\le \eta$

So $\forall \epsilon >0 \,\,\, \exists \delta>0 \,\,\,x \in (a,b):0<|x-b|< \delta \Longrightarrow |f(x)-\eta|<\epsilon$ indeed holds for the right side, which implies $\lim\limits_{x\nearrow b}f$ indeed exists!

For the second limit I would just do the same in the other direction :)

Could someone look over it and give some feedback?